# jquery add multiple parameters to links within a div with specific id

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="links">
   <a href="http://something.domain.com">link></a>
   <a href="http://something.domain.com">link></a>
   <a href="http://something.domain.com">link></a>
   <a href="http://something.domain.com">link></a>
   ........
</div>
```

How can I add multiple parameters to these links from within div with id links?

EDIT:

So the links will be like this:

```
<a href="http://something.domain.com?param=1&param2=2&param3=3">link</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by parameters?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Are the params going to be the same for each link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
$("#links a").each(function(){

    $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href")+"?param=1&param2=2&param3=3");

})
```